# VBA to highlight the entire column with the current date

Tags: excel, highlight, vba

I have information running through ("B:I"). The dates are located in I.

I wanted to make a VBA code that will find the current date and highlight that entire column.

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formating?

Comment: when I tried using conditional formatting it only highlighted the date and not everything else

Comment: You need to apply the rule to all the columns and make the reference to column I absolute.

Comment: I am fairly new with using conditional formatting. Can you give me an example of what that would look like?

Comment: Highlight columns B through I.  Click on conditional formatting.  Add new rule.  Use formula.  Put in this formula: `=$I1 = Today()`.  Choose your desired formatting, click ok on both screens.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that

Comment: Try this formula: `=INT($I1)=INT(TODAY())`  If that does not work then your dates are not true dates but text that look like dates.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that got it done!